# Unable to install spring IDE in eclipse mars/neon

Tags: spring-mvc

getting the below error while installing spring IDE from eclipse market place

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http: //dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.8.4.RELEASE/e4.5/features/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.feature_3.8.4.201703310634-RELEASE.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http: //dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.8.4.RELEASE/e4.5/plugins/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.graph_3.8.4.201703310634-RELEASE.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http ://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.8.4.RELEASE/e4.5/features/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature_3.8.4.201703310634-RELEASE.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http: //dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.8.4.RELEASE/e4.5/plugins/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.core_3.8.4.201703310634-RELEASE.jar.
Read timed out

Answer (score 0):

Check for Eclipse updates at first

Goto Windows-> peferences -> Install/Update -> Available software Sites,update "http://download.springsource.com" instead of "http://dist.springsource.com". restart Eclipse, and add it back.

And select help>install new software>contact all update sites (check)

I did this for Eclipse Mars version

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Eclipse Oxygen Release (4.7.0) and I followed the solution suggested by @Vasath.

In the list of Available software sites, I edited "SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 4.7" by replacing 
`http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.7` with 
`http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.7`.

It worked, Spring IDE is installed and working fine.